# Can we generate custom logs for Sagemaker notebook instance in CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

CloudWatch records logs for Sagemaker instance such as Kernel Started, Kernel shutdown, Notebook Saved etc by default. Though, I want to list some custom logs along with these default logs.

Please have a look at the picture attached.

[Sample image of How default logs for a Sagemaker notebook instance look in CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g680f.png)

The goal is to be able to see some custom logs with these. For example - 'Cell 1 executed!'

Comment: what happens is you just use the logging module or the print function inside your cells?

Comment: The logs get printed below the cell but nothing in the cloud watch logs!

Comment: according to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-cloudwatch.html) your prints should go to cloudwatch, check if you are watching the right logstream, alternatively.. what happens if you use the python logging module ?

Comment: Can you please point out where exactly in the docs is it mentioned? I have used logging module as well as the STDOUT and STDERR streams, but none of these methods is sending any custom logs to CloudWatch! Can you please try it out and mention if something works for you.

Comment: @HarshvardhanPalawat did you find a solution? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter server emits logs to stdout. So for notebook instances at least you can access the logs from CloudWatch. These would be under the /aws/sagemaker/NotebookInstances log group.

You can follow the below steps to automatically log kernel level logs to CW -

1. Choose Notebook instances.
2. In the list of notebook instances, choose the notebook instance for which you want to view Jupyter logs by selecting the Notebook instance Name.
3. This will bring you to the details page for that notebook instance.
4. Under Monitor on the notebook instance details page, choose View logs.
5. In the CloudWatch console, choose the log stream for your notebook instance. Its name is in the form NotebookInstanceName/jupyter.log.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/jupyter-logs.html