# Make logs visible from sagemaker on CloudWatch

Tags: python, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I have tried to use print function & logging module in my notebook script to make logs available on CloudWatch: my goal is to track the sagemaker notebook usage **per cell**.

Do you know how to make the logs I want to see visible on CloudWatch ? Otherwise do you know how to track the usage per cell without having to use print functions / logging module ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we generate custom logs for Sagemaker notebook instance in CloudWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056363/can-we-generate-custom-logs-for-sagemaker-notebook-instance-in-cloudwatch)

Comment: Thanks but I've already seen this link, the person who posted the question is having the same problem as me, and it is still unresolved (quote from their comment: "I have used logging module as well as the STDOUT and STDERR streams, but none of these methods is sending any custom logs to CloudWatch")